# closeing download option for IE with selenium and robot

Tags: java, selenium

Trying to find a way to close the option to download a file from a link in IE. Looked up a robot that could use the keyboard " Alt+Q" that would be the desired outcome, but when I go to run the program it gets stuck at the Robit() part.

When I click off the Webbrowser I'm working with the commands go through. In whatever application I'm working with at the time. Would love some help

```
public static void V_home(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException, AWTException{
    driver.get(VUrl);
    ...
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download School and District File")).click();
    Robit();
}
public static void Robit() throws InterruptedException, AWTException{
         Robot robot = new Robot();
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? just before calling your method `Robit();` put atleast 5 seconds of wait

Comment: drawback of using Robot class is that you have to remain present on the browser window when that particular line of code executes